# Functional Principal Component Analysis (FPCA): Mean Function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, functional-data-analysis

How does one calculate a mean function in Functional Principal Component Analysis (FPCA) given a data set with an unknown distribution? (A theoretical approach if possible)

I am wanting to implement R's fpca.sc function in MATLAB and/or python. Does anyone know how to do this?

$$ $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_principal_component_analysis

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/refund/versions/0.1-16/topics/fpca.sc

Comment: (I removed the `r` tag as R itself is not a critical part of the question and I added the `functional-data-analysis` tag as the question is related to FDA.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The estimation of the mean function depends on the underlying FPCA implementation. `refund` uses spline smoothing (as it makes extensive use of the package `mgcv`), while other packages like `fdapace` use locally weighted linear smoothers. A simple Python-based FPCA implementation I have found [here](https://github.com/akoryagin/FPCA) also uses local-linear smoothing.

Both approaches (i.e. using splines or locally weighted linear smoothers) are equally valid as they provide a non-parametric estimate of the mean trend. `fdapace` comes with a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdapace/vignettes/fdapaceVig.html) that might come in as handy as a general blue-print on how to make an overall FPCA routine.

As you make a particular hint to MATLAB/Python I would suggest looking at the MATLAB package [PACE](http://www.stat.ucdavis.edu/PACE/) which is developed by the same people behind `fdapace`.  The canonical "PACE" reference is *[Functional Data Analysis for Sparse Longitudinal Data](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27590579)* by Yao, Mueller, and Wang (2005). I am unaware of any widely used Python FDA packages,

In general, Functional Data Analysis involves a lot of smoothing. In many cases core practical differences between methodologies are actually different smoothing approaches.